# Setting up htaccess redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Does anyone know how I could achieve the following with .htaccess?

1. If the file does not exist but folder exists, redirect to folder
2. If the file is in the root directory, or folder does not exist, redirect to home page "/"

For example, if we have to take a request to www.domain.com/folder/file.html:

1. If /folder/file.html exists, we just show it as is, no redirect.
2. If /folder/file.html does NOT existing but /folder/ does exist, we redirect to /folder/
3. If then /folder/ does not exists we redirect to "/" We need this done in a generic way so that we do not need to hardcode the folder or file names into the .htaccess file.

Should work for all file types with a way to set up exclusions (both for folders and filetypes)

Comment: What do you actually mean by 1.1? If the folder exists, redirect to folder... If you already request the folder, then what should that redirection do?!?

Comment: Can you link to said documentation? I've tried the following:

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/?$ "" [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)([^/]+/?)$  $1 [PT]

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Checking 1. is not a problem, but to check 2., you would need to “cut off” the filename and suffix from the requested URL first - and that is not so trivial. I would rather just specify a script as the 404 error document, and then handle this checking of what part of the path actually exists inside that script.